# pjsip build for iOS 5, won't make

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ffmpeg, pjsip

I retrieved the latest build from the **SVN trunk** on Friday and attempted to build following the directions on the getting started wiki.

`make` dep seems to execute without any problems, but make fails on Samples.mak.  It appears there are no rules to make any of the samples when the platform is "arm-apple-darwin9".

If I open the `Xcode` project at this point, `libavcodec` and all it's related libraries are missing as well as `LibSDL`.  There's not mention of a requirement to install SDL and `ffmpeg` beforehand, so not sure what to do there.

Comment: did you configure for ios first?

Comment: Yes, did you chage the config_site.h file?? there are a couple of line to be added. The file does not exist by default.

Answer (score 0):

Please add some framework is required for run pjsip and also checked config_site.h this file available or not if not found then add this file. some code also may to write in config_site.h file .